# I can use Maven from Eclipse, but not from command line

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jenkins

I'm starting with spring boot, and maven, and jenkins.

And I'm trying to create a Jenkins Job that builds a Spring boot app, but I'm asked about a MAVEN_HOME path.

I found out I don't have such a thing.

So my question is How can I use Maven from eclipse, but not from command line?

is it an eclipse plugin and therefore it is not available to outside eclipse?

should I install maven in the machine and set environment variable even though I can use it in eclipse?

Should I keep the same maven version in jenkins and eclipse?

This is my output when i run mvn -version

```
mvn -version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Have you ried to read apache maven manual? https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: As an additional pointer to what @Matteo mentions, you might want to search about both "setting environment variables" and "adding executable to the path" for the OS you are using.

Comment: On linux system, if you don't need any specific version of java or maven,the default installation (es on ubuntu 18, sudo apt install maven)

Comment: @Matteo Yes I read it but didn't wanted to perform any job without first understanding whats was going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is included in Eclipse. To run Maven from command line, you need to install a command line Maven and set the PATH variable for it.

I would try to make sure that both Maven versions have the same major and minor version.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I've performed a host installation of maven, and then configured eclipse to use the host maven, instead of the embedded version.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has its own **embedded** Maven environment.
You can also switch another installed one. 
Check below directory

```
     Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installation
```

Comment: Hi, your input was valuable for me (upvoted in the same day)

Answer (score 1):

Please use maven wrapper if you want consistency between all you tools such as 
**Maven at Jenkins ( or any other build tool for sake )** and try to build your check its version using

```
mvnw --version
```

or `./mvnw --version`

**This is platform independent choice.**

Comment: Hi! this was not what I asked, but sure it was valuable to me. (upvoted in the same day)